# Que multiple dialogFragments to display one after the other

Tags: android, iteration, android-dialogfragment

If I have an `ArrayList<DialogFragment>` containing `DialogFragment`s of unknown size, how can I programmatically cue up each one so that once the first one is dismissed, the next one is shown, and so on?

```
for (int i = 0; i < tutorialViews.size(); i++) {
    final int current = i;
    DialogFragment someDialogFragment = dialogFragmentList.get(i);

    if (i == 0) {
        someDialogFragment .show(activity.get().getSupportFragmentManager(), "some_dialog_fragment");
    } 

    if (i + 1 != dialogFragmentList.size() - 1) {
        someDialogFragment.getDialog().setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                dialogFragmentList.get(current + 1).show(activity.get().getSupportFragmentManager(), "more_dialog_fragments");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Unforunately this doesn't work since the `dialog` object within a `dialogFragment` isn't instantiated yet, giving a `nullPointerException` for the `getDialog()` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own interface to callback when the fragmentdialog is closed.

```
OnDialogFragHide mListener;

public interface OnDialogFragHide {
    public void onFragmentDismissed();
}

public void setOnFragDismissedListener(OnDialogFragHide listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}
```

Register the interface in the for loop

```
if (i == 0) {
    tutorial.show(activity.get().getSupportFragmentManager(), "smoking_hawt");
} 

if (i != tutorialViews.size() - 1) {
    tutorial.setOnFragDismissedListener(new OnDialogFragHide() {
        @Override
        public void onFragmentDismissed() {
            tutorialViews.get(current + 1).show(activity.get().getSupportFragmentManager(), "some_tag");
        }
    });
}
```

Call upon the listener whenever the fragment is closed (i.e. in the **`FragmentDialog`**'s `onDismiss()` and `onCancel()` methods, *NOT* the **DIALOG**'s `onDismiss` / `onCancel` listeners.

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    if (mListener != null && !dismissed) {
        dismissed = true;
        mListener.onFragmentDismissed();
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "DialogFragmentDismissed not set");
    }
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
}

@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    if (mListener != null && dismissed) {
        dismissed = true;
        mListener.onFragmentDismissed();
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "DialogFragmentDismissed not set");
    }
    super.onCancel(dialog);
}
```

the `dismissed` boolean is for good measure to make the listener isn't called twice.